# Java 2d array using if else

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Im trying to find the min and max value in this 2d array. I get the correct output, (-10 as the min, 40 as the max) but I cant seem to pass the second test, which is {73,0} Any ideas?

```
public class ArraysKeyValue {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
  final int NUM_ROWS = 2;
  final int NUM_COLS = 2;
  int [][] milesTracker = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
  int i = 0;        
  int j = 0;
  int maxMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop
  int minMiles = 0; // Assign with first element in milesTracker before loop

  milesTracker[0][0] = -10;
  milesTracker[0][1] = 20;
  milesTracker[1][0] = 30;
  milesTracker[1][1] = 40;

  maxMiles = milesTracker[1][1];
  minMiles = milesTracker[0][0];

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
          if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
              minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
              maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }
         if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
                  maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }
      }
  }

  System.out.println("Min miles: " + minMiles);
  System.out.println("Max miles: " + maxMiles);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, update your code accordingly,

```
.....

 for (j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
          if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
              minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
              maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }
         if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles){
                  maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }else if(milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles ){
                    minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
          }

      }

.....
```

Comment: You don't want an `else if`. It wouldn't set `minMiles` in some cases.

Comment: @radoh may i know which case ?

Comment: Actually if minMiles=maxMiles=milesTracker[0][0] is set, this might even be a faster solution (a value can only be smaller than `minMiles`, when it is also smaller than `maxMiles`).

Comment: Hm, you're right, I stand corrected. I was thinking of a general case when you initialize `maxValue` as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `minValue` as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you forgot to adjust `minMiles` accordingly. Add another `if`

```
 if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles){
      minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if clean your code:

```
minMiles = maxMiles = milesTracker[0][0];  //init min and max as index = 0
for (i = 1; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {  //start from index = 1
    for (j = 1; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
        if (milesTracker[i][j] > maxMiles) {
            maxMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
        else if (milesTracker[i][j] < minMiles) {
            minMiles = milesTracker[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```